# PostgreSQL, finding elements by value in numeric JSON arrays

Tags: postgresql, array, json

I have a table defined as:

```
create table dummy (jdata jsonb);
```

I inserted the following two rows:

```
insert into dummy values ('["dog","cat","elephant","waffle"]');
insert into dummy values ('[1,2,3,4]');
```

I am trying to make use of the jsonb `?&` operator which lets you ask the question "Do all of these key/element strings exist?"

An example using the string fields works:

```
select * from dummy where jdata ?& array['cat','dog'];
            jdata                 
--------------------------------------
["dog", "cat", "elephant", "waffle"]
(1 row)
```

But, trying to do this with an array that contains numbers does not work:

```
select * from dummy where jdata ?& array['1','2'];
  jdata 
  -------
(0 rows)

select * from dummy where jdata ?& array['1','2'];
 jdata 
 -------
 (0 rows)

select * from dummy where jdata ?& array[1,2];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ?& integer[]
LINE 1: select * from dummy where jdata ?& array[1,2];
                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I know that the `?&` operator works on text arrays, but therein lies the problem.  Does anyone know how to get the json operators to work on numeric arrays?

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong operator, you want [`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) (added in 9.4). `?&` only operates over JSON objects.

```
SELECT
  j,
  j @> '"dog"'::jsonb AS hasDog,
  j @> '["dog","waffle"]' AS hasDogAndWaffle,
  j @> '5'   AS has5,
  j @> '42'  AS has42
FROM ( VALUES
  ('[5,2,3]'::jsonb),
  ('["dog","cat","elephant","waffle"]'::jsonb)
)
  AS t(j);

                  j                   | hasdog | hasdogandwaffle | has5 | has42 
--------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+------+-------
 [5, 2, 3]                            | f      | f               | t    | f
 ["dog", "cat", "elephant", "waffle"] | t      | t               | f    | f
(2 rows)
```

If all you're storing is numbers, you should consider using [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) and not jsonb. It should be a lot faster.